# How to hide return data type implementation from a user

Tags: function, types, language-agnostic, double

I've been reading about abstraction lately, as well as composition, and interfaces. What I've been wondering is this. Say I have a simple class that does some work and returns a value of type double.

If I wanted to protect the user from changes to the return type, how might I design a class so the user doesn't have to worry whether I used a double, or decided to use a float, or worse. At some point, in a more complicated scenario, I might want to make an implementation change. But, if the return type is coupled to the user of my class, that would be a disaster trying to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You should create that variable as private and it's value can be modified only through that method, for example:

```
    class whatever {
private double x;
public void setX(double s)
{
x = d;
}
public double getX()
{
return x;
}
```

now the setX() method is only way to change that variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a simple class that does some work and returns a value of type double.

I assume you mean that there is a function within the class that is responsible for returning the value and that there are other functions in the class responsible for internal calculations (with respect to the user).

> how might I design a class so the user doesn't have to worry whether I used a double, or decided to use a float, or worse. At some point, in a more complicated scenario, I might want to make an implementation change. But, if the return type is coupled to the user of my class, that would be a disaster trying to modify.

This is a "backwards compatibility" issue. By exposing your function to the user you basically signed a contract stating that this function will always return values consistent with its previous implementations (until the "end of life" of that product version). The internal implementation, that is, all the functions used for calculations are changeable provided this does not alter the result.

You can always add and expose more methods. As an abstract example, suppose you exposed a function that returns an `int` because this is how accurate you can calculate. The user should always be able to use it - if you change that it will break all of their code. Now you find a way to have floating point precision, so you add a function which returns `float` *in addition* to the previous one. The user will (hopefully) now adjust to this change and by the time you are able to remove the `int` function (due to "end of life") everything would still work.